# Running Appium 1.6 tests on iOS 10

Tags: appium, ios10

is xcuitest the only driver that can run appium test on iOS 10 device?

I can't find a simple example or explaination for it in the web.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge XCUITest is the driver appium uses for apps that are created from xcode 8 (aka appium currently only supports XCUITest for iOS 10.x). IOS 10 must use XCUITest where IOS 9 can use UIAutomator or XCUITest depending on what the app is formatted to. You will need XCUI driver to run appium on iOS.

Are there any technical pieces you need to help get this running?